# Sending CSV to client over SSE on file generation

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django on the fly so sorry if this is a stupid question, I think the answer is no.

I'm wanting to push a generated CSV file to the client and download it automatically after it's finished. I was originally going to create a view for this, but I'm unable to call a view function from an external function. Views passes form data to an external function to process.

Views.py:

```
def viewsFunc(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    csvUpload = pd.read_csv(request.FILES['filename'])
    userName = request.POST['Username']
    password = request.POST['Password']

    x = threading.Thread(target=externalScript.externalFunc, args=[csvUpload, userName, password])
    x.setDaemon(False)
    x.start()
    return render(request, 'app/htmlPage.html')
```

externalScript.py:

```
def externalFunc(csvUpload, userName, password):
    'do stuff & sends data to client, create CSV'
    send_event('test', 'message', {'text': data})
```

As you can see, I'm unable to return `response` from here outside of views.py so I'm not sure if it's possible or what best practice would be. Best case scenario is I pass the CSV to the client without saving to the server.

How terrible would it be to do in views.py? It feels "hacky":

```
x = threading.Thread(target=externalScript.externalFunc, args=[csvUpload, userName, password])
if x.isAlive() == False:
    csvDownloadViewFunc()



def csvDownloadViewFunc():
        response = HttpResponse(
        content_type='text/csv',
        headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="testForm.csv"'},
    )
    return response
```